# DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 2

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am really confused now why the following snippet results in DateTimeParseException.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
        String date = "Mon, 10 Sep 2018 23:57:09 UTC";
        System.out.println(dtf.parse(date));
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon, 10 Sep 2018 23:57:09 UTC' could not be parsed at index 2
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
    at com.sample.binding.bitronvideo.driver.BitronVideoRecordingDriver.main(BitronVideoRecordingDriver.java:448)
```

I would really appreciate further help.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Based on my limited experimentation, the parser seems unwilling to attempt to parse the day (and probably the month) name values without more context, ie, which language it should use.  I changed the formatter to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.UK)` and was able to get your code to work

Comment: If you could get a string with an offset of either `GMT` or `+0000` rather then `UTC`, it would conform with [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME). I realize it’s probably not an option for you, but wanted to mention it in case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't get the exception. So Checking your profile I saw that your locale is in Germany so i tried this and got the exception.

```
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = 
             java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", 
                                                       Locale.GERMANY);
    String date = "Mon, 10 Sep 2018 23:57:09 UTC";
    System.out.println(dtf.parse(date));
```

And the [shordays for German](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/de-CH/index.html) are :

> Short weekdays    So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa

Try with this code and I bet it will work

```
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf =
              java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
    String date = "Mo, 10 Sep 2018 23:57:09 UTC";
    System.out.println(dtf.parse(date));
```

But for your String Date to work just use UK or US Locale by passing an argument

```
    java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf =
           java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", 
                                                         Locale.UK);
    String date = "Mon, 10 Sep 2018 23:57:09 UTC";
    System.out.println(dtf.parse(date));
```

Comment: Nice analysis and answer.