# Android: Parsing datetime with timezone using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, android, java-time, timezone-offset, datetime-parsing

Convert string `'2018-08-27T16:40:02+08:00'` to datetime using DateTimeFormatter

```
 private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
 String rawDateString = "2018-08-27T16:40:02+08:00"

 DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = 
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
 LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(rawDateString, dateTimeFormatter);
 return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

but this returns `DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 19`

I saw some similar issue like this

[DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266975/datetimeparseexception-text-could-not-be-parsed-at-index-2)

but I dont see any sample with timezone on datetime format.

Comment: Please also see my comments under this question: [Migrating to Java 8 DateTime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031601/migrating-to-java-8-datetime). You don’t need the formatter. But you do need to parse into an `OffsetDateTIme` (a `LocalDateTime` won’t work). `OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(rawDateString);`. It also simplifies the conversion: `return Date.from(odt.toInstant());`. In my time zone the result is `Mon Aug 27 10:40:02 CEST 2018`.

Comment: Other than that the answers that are relevant to you are [this one by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46017622/5772882) and [this one by deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56834598/5772882).

Comment: A detail, the exception I get from your code says *Text '2018-08-27T16:40:02+08:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19*.

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree with this solution of using OffsetDateTIme to simplify the parsing of date with timezone for this kind of format "2018-08-27T16:40:02+08:00"

Answer (score 1):

You neeed to specify timezone offset in your format as well. Like that:

```
 String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
```

See the link bellow:
https://www.journaldev.com/17899/java-simpledateformat-java-date-format

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. It’s not incorrect, but (1) the OP doesn’t need a formatter at all, so we don’t need to fix that part. (2) The link is irrelevant since the OP is wisely using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, not the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`.